# How to check when the timer tick event occurs

Tags: c#, timer

I need to make a splash screen that is visible for 5000 milliseconds before closing. I pass in 5000 to my SplashScreen form constructor and set `timer1.Interval = time`. I can't seem to find a straightforward answer online and I don't have much experience with timers. I assume that I need to show the splash screen, start the timer, check for when `timer1.Tick` occurs, and close the form but I don't know the syntax on how to do that.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen(5000, appLogo, "Text Editor", "Copyright (c) 2020", "John Doe");

            splash.timer1.Enabled = true;
            splash.ShowDialog();
            splash.timer1.Start();

            // Wait for Tick event to occur.....

            splash.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You don't "wait for tick to occur".  You assign an event handler to be invoked when the timer expires.

Comment: There is about 6 different `Timer` classes in `C#`, which one is yours? Also I'm pretty sure, that `splash.timer1.Enabled = true;` and `splash.timer1.Start();` are doing the same thing, you may safly remove one of this lines

Comment: You don't check, it tells you. However if you would like pause code for an event, you could use a `ManualResetEvent` or some other synchronisation object

Comment: @vasily.sib System.Windows.Forms.Timer. I'm thinking that I need to create an event handler and then close the splash screen and open the text editor when the timer expires?

Comment: The best way to learn how to use code, is to read the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.8 it gives you an example of how you would go about this

Comment: Also, if you place your timer in `SplashScreen` - then you should start and listen for it in `SplashScreen`. If you start and listen for it in `Form1` - then move your `timer` to `Form1`. Also, keep your class fields `private`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SplashScreen form, you need to define the Tick event:

```
timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(CloseForm);
```

That calls a method to close the form:

```
private void CloseForm(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up with last night.